# Jmeter # of request starts to drop after few hours

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Can someone help me identify what's wrong with my Jmeter, Currently I'm running 200 users and will generate 6000 request per minute. on First few hours the request is consistent at 6000 but after few hours it starts to drop.

Machine & Server is hosted on AWS
FYI: I'm currently running this on Ubuntu CLI

Command used: `./jmeter -n -t ES_Scenario1_Endurancetest.jmx -l /data/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/bin/result/loadtest/ES_EnduranceTest_aggregateResult_100.csv &`

Upon invocation of single API it returns more than 6000 lines of code

Jmeter Configuration

[image: Jmeter Thread Configuration]

[image: Cache Manager]

[image: Jmeter Configuration]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you asked this question in the JMeter community on GitHub? https://github.com/apache/jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want from us exactly? Your [soak test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Soak_testing) fails and now you need to find the reason for the failure.

Given you follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) article JMeter should be stable enough and suitable for the soak testing without degradation of the performance over the time.

If you believe that JMeter causes requests slowing down you can use a profiler tool like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/features/) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) to check what causes the slowing down. Alternatively instead of your endpoint you can try using a different one like http://example.com or https://blazedemo.com and see if the problem is reproducible. If yes - [raise an issue in JMeter project](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

However I believe JMeter is quite mature and free of obvious [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) so my expectation is it's a bug in the application you're trying to test so consider applying the same exercise with [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools).